# Regular expression for first name with some conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JavaScript regular expression for a first name with the following requirement:

1. No numbers and the following characters are invalid: `` ~`?(!^*¨ˆ;@=$%{}[]|\/<>#“., ``
2. Should not have more than 3 words
3. No preceding or trailing spaces
4. Minimum of 2 characters

I did it with two separate regular expressions:
First one is:  for no numbers and invalid characters:

```
^[A-Za-z][^\d~`?!^*¨ˆ;@=$%{}\[\]\|\\\/<>#“.,]*$
```

The second one is for not more than 3 words:

```
^[A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z]+){0,2}$
```

I need a single regular expression which handles all 4 above conditions (or at least 3 as we can set min-length condition for the 4th one).

Comment: So, does name contains only alphabets? Please provide the list of all the allowed characters

Comment: Isn't `^[A-Z]([A-Za-z])+(\s[A-Za-z]{2,}){0,2}$` enough?

Comment: @Amit I think the minimum of 2 characters is total, not per word...

Comment: @Mahesh: Please provide sample valid and invalid input.

Comment: Yes, minimum of 2 characters total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex that will conform to your requirements:

```
^(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})(?![^\d~`?!^*¨ˆ;@=$%{}\[\]|\\\/<>#“.,]*[\d~`?!^*¨ˆ;@=$%{}\[\]|\\\/<>#“.,])\S+(?: \S+){0,2}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI2qH7/5)

**EXPLANATION**:

- `^` - Anchoring the string at the beginning
- `(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})` - A positive look-ahead that checks if we have at least 2 English characters in the string
- ``` (?![^\d~``?!^*¨ˆ;@=$%{}\[\]|\\\/<>#“.,]*[\d~``?!^*¨ˆ;@=$%{}\[\]|\\\/<>#“.,]) ``` - A negative look-ahead checking if there is no forbidden characters (optimized according to the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast)) (could not format it well, had to double "`" symbol)
- `\S{2,}` - A word (a sequence of non-whitespace) consisting of at least 2 characters
- `(?: \S+){0,2}` - 2 words consisting of at least 1 character
- `$` - End of string.

Comment: Minimum of 2 characters is for whole first name. So it might be AB, A B.

Comment: OK, I replace `{0,2}` with `+`. Now, it should accept `AB A B`.

Comment: I think \S{2, }  doesn't match the requirement. Full name should contains minimum of two characters.  e.g Full name =      A   B

Comment: Other examples :  Full name = A B C
Full name =  Mack Rogger Shane
Full name = A Mack C
Full name = A B Mack
Full name = John B C
Full name = John Mack C

Comment: Do you mean you only want to allow English alphabet characters? Then why bother with the digits and "invalid" special characters? Just use [`^(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+){0,2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/bI2qH7/4).

Comment: Not only English alphabet characters, it might contains other characters e.g. apostrophe, &, ( ). e.g.  full name = Mack's & C.

But it's okay. If I use your first provided solution :

^(?![^\d~`?!^*¨ˆ;@=$%{}\[\]|\\\/<>#“.,]*[\d~`?!^*¨ˆ;@=$%{}\[\]|\\\/<>#“.,])\S{1,}(?:\s*\S{1,}){0,2}$
it should work.

I will use angular js ng-minlength for minimum 2 characters condition

Comment: Please check the update, I added the check for at least 2 English letters. [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/bI2qH7/5).

Comment: One quick question regarding first part of regx :         
(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})  what is the use of ?: non-capturing group for A-Za-z characters.

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that does not create a backreference. So that we only had just 1 capturing group, to avoid overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define set of available characters. For simplicity assume:

```
[^0123456789]
```

and do something like this:

define that one segment minimum length is 2

```
[^0123456789]{2,}
```

construct Regex that accept only 1-3 words:

```
[^0123456789]{2,}(\s[^0123456789]{2,}(\s[^0123456789]{2,})?)?
```

Comment: You can use `[^0-9]`, you don't have to specify every character. Use ranges. Also I would whitelist rather than blacklist: `[a-z\-]`. The final should look like this: `/[a-z\-]{2,}(\s[a-z\-]{2,})?\s[a-z\-]{2,})?)/i`

Comment: I intentionally use this form because @Mahesh define characters that he don't want to use

Answer (score 0):

Actually you only need a RegExp for the first condition. What you basically want is names with only word characters except for numbers, but there still might be spaces:

```
name.match(/^([a-zA-Z]|\s)$/)
```

For the second condition you can write `name.split(/\s+/).length <= 3`.

For the third it is just `name.trim()`.

And the fourth one you figured it out for yourself with `name.length >= 2`.

So to put it all together:

```
var name = "    JOe      John   Thomas  ";
name = name.trim();
if (name.match(/^([a-zA-Z]|\s)$/) && name.split(/\s+/).length <= 3 && name.length >=2) {
  console.log("name is valid!");
}
```